# deleted documents in couchdb view

Tags: couchdb

how to remove the deleted documents in couchdb

when temporary View is running on couchdb futon. I am getting deleted documents also.

```
    if(!doc._deleted) and if(!_deleted_conflicts)
```

The above condition is used in Temporary view. But the problem is repated.

Please anyone can help me out to solve this.

Comment: This is a bug - deleted documents should not be appeared in views. Could you please add comment at [COUCHDB-1279](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-1279) ticket about your Couch and how this problem could be reproduced? Example of buggy database will be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Add one condition in your view like,

```
function(doc){
   if(!doc._deleted){
       emit(null,doc);
   }
}
```

then you can avoid the deleted documents in view result.